# Why do I see cookies set in chrome although the "block cookies" option is on

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

I have both "block sites from setting any data" and "block third-party cookies and data" turned on. However, after I clear all cookies and browse a few sites, I see a lot of cookies have been set in chrome (version 26.0.1410.64 m). What gives?

Comment: I have this problem too. Did you ever figure out why cookie blocking wasn't working as expected?